File upload service with moleculer
I have a service file, and I'm sending a file to the http://localhost:4000/uploads URL using the "file" field via POST in Postman. However, in my code, context.meta.$multipart is coming out as undefined, and the file is not being saved to the public directory.
api.service
`
const ApiGateway = require("moleculer-web");

module.exports = {
  name: "api",
  version: 1,
  mixins: [ApiGateway],

  settings: {
    port: 8080,
    path: "/upload",
    routes: [
      {
        path: "",
 
        bodyParsers: {
          json: false,
          urlencoded: false
        },

        mappingPolicy: "restrict",
        aliases: {
         
          "POST /multi": {
            type: "multipart",
            // Action level busboy config
            busboyConfig: {
              limits: {
                files: 3
              }
            },
            action: "v1.assets.upload"
          },
          // File upload from HTML multipart form
          "POST /": "multipart:v1.assets.upload",

          // File upload from AJAX or cURL
          "PUT /": "stream:v1.assets.upload"
        },
        // Route level busboy config.
    
        busboyConfig: {
          limits: {
            files: 1
          }
        }
      }
    ],

    assets: {
      folder: "./public"
    }
  }
};

`
assets.service.js
`
module.exports = {
    name: "assets",
    version: 1,
    actions: {
      upload: {
        handler(context) {
          console.log("params", context.params.meta);
          console.log("context.meta.$multipart", context.meta.$multipart);
        }
      }
    }
  };

`
I tried both POST and PUT, and even tested it by creating a website, but I still couldn't resolve the error. It returns 200 OK in Postman, but the file is not uploaded, and both console.log statements in the assets.service.js file are returning undefined.

the file will not shown in the code just it name will appair in ctx.meta , but after passing it in the pipe  =>   ctx.params.pipe(f); you will find it ur destination folder
first of all you need to import
import path from "path";
import fs from 'fs';

handler(ctx: any): any {
// to see your params
                console.log({
                    multipart:ctx.meta.$multipart,
                    params:ctx.params,
                    $params: ctx.meta.$params,
                    meta:ctx.meta
                });
// here is the tricks
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                   const filePath = path.join("destination_folder_here", ctx.meta.filename );
                    const f = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
                    f.on("close", () => {
                     
                        resolve({
                            multipart:ctx.meta.$multipart,
                            params:ctx.params,
                            $params: ctx.meta.$params,
                            meta:ctx.meta
                        });
                    });

                    ctx.params.on("error", (err: any) => {
                        console.log(" error ", err.message);
                        reject(err);
                        f.destroy(err);
                    });

                    ctx.params.pipe(f);
                }); 
            }

